# Firebase Functions.EventContext becomes undefined after update

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

fuctions.EventContext gives error when trying to get uid after updating to latest firebase (6.10.0)

I had a test project working fine. I updated firebase tools, typescript and create a new project with the same code. Suddenly the project gives error on EventContext.auth.uid . When mouseover context or auth it says
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

```
export const onAccountTransferCreated = functions.database
.ref('/data_transfer/from_data/user_data/{transferPas}')
.onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {


console.log(`Snapshot = ${snapshot.toJSON}`)
console.log(`Context = ${context.auth.uid}`)
admin.auth().getUser(context.auth.uid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context` is an [EventContext](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext) type object.  As you can see from the API documentation for its [auth property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext#.auth), it might be null or undefined:

> This field is only populated for Realtime Database triggers and
>   Callable functions. For an unauthenticated user, this field is null.
>   For Firebase admin users and event types that do not provide user
>   information, this field will not exist.

The TypeScript definition for EventContext.auth is this:

```
export interface EventContext {
    auth?: {
        uid: string;
        token: object;
    };
}
```

Notice the ? after `auth`.  That means the property doesn't have to exist.

TypeScript (in strict mode) is warning you that you could have a problem at runtime when this property is missing.  You must check it before you use it:

```
export const onAccountTransferCreated = functions.database
.ref('/data_transfer/from_data/user_data/{transferPas}')
.onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {

    console.log(`Snapshot = ${snapshot.toJSON}`)
    if (context.auth) {
        console.log(`Context = ${context.auth.uid}`)
        admin.auth().getUser(context.auth.uid)
    }
})
```

Or, you can turn of TypeScript strict mode, which I don't recommend.  It's always better to do the check in order to avoid crashes at runtime.

Comment: The link is broken